# Python Chatterbot training

Tags: python, chatbot, training-data

So, I am trying to make a chat bot system for my school project using python chatterbot and chatterbot-corpus. I have read everywhere that you have to train your chat bot. I have to make a restaurant ordering simulation on it. If i train the chat bot with orders and data will it be stored in it? Like say i do a ListTrain and provide it with data like "Hey this is our menu. We have this for this price" then the customer will say, oh thank you, I want to order this. The bot takes the order and says sure here is your order number.
Now, when I actually run my program, and ask the same question, will do the same as trained? Would I need to delete my training before running it? And if i do, will it still remember?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with code, which is the main focus of this site, so this question may go unanswered or get closed. It seems like you're asking a general ML question. There are StackExchange sites specifically for ML, so I suggest finding one from this list which fits your needs better: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms